# Variable seems to be undefined and defined at the same time?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm having some trouble with theses lines.

```
this.stringifiedProducts = JSON.stringify(this.products)
this.parsedProducts = JSON.parse(this.stringifiedProducts)
```

I get an **SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0** when executing it. **this.products** is JSON comming from an API. The strange thing is that when I dump **stringifiedProducts** or just **products** it shows me this :

```
[{"id":1,"productName":"Tomates","unit_id":1,"stock":12,"picture":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NjIpLCBxdWFsaXR5ID0gOTgK/9sAQwABAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQECAQEBAQECAQEBAgICAgICAgICAwMEAwMDAwMCAgMEAwMEBAQEBAIDBQUEBAUEBAQE etc...
```

And it continues for more than 170'000 lines of hardcoded jpeg... So how could it be undefined ? Even an if statement says that's not undefined.

**Edit :** I can't get my hand on the code in question. I was new on js and wasn't confident with asynchronous operations. It parsed the json directly and wasn't waiting on the promise to fulfuill.

Comment: you mean if you console the data it is showing right?

Comment: Why would you stringify something, only to then parse the result of that again on the next line? // Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: The API most likely returns a JSON string, not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is directed at the second line of code @ `JSON.parse`.

There is most likely a problem at that point.

It could be that you are attempting to parse while performing the asynchronous request to retrieve the `stringifiedProducts` data.

Comment: I forgot about that but yes, this.products was given from an asynchronous request but stringifying and parsing were done outside so it didn't wait on it. Sorry not really used to asynchronous dev. Thanks !